# Cannot open database test requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: asp.net, iis

i have hosted a website for a LAN for saving some data into to db.but i am getting this error:
Cannot open database test requested by the login. The login failed.

Comment: Check your connection string

Answer (score 0):

See this link for more info.

Cannot open Database test Login Failed [link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/)